# facesContext.validationFailed is coming back null

Tags: jsf-2

For what reason facesContext.validationFailed could be null? (in a postBack where there are errors..) 
I had to resort to an ugly `if (#{fn:containsIgnoreCase(facesContext.maximumSeverity,'ERROR')}) showSecurePopup('confirm');` because facesContext.validationFailed is coming back null..

the test code is:

```
<h:form>
   <h:messages />
   <br></br>

   <h:outputText value="Validation failed: #{facesContext.validationFailed}" />
   <br></br>

   <h:outputLabel for="field1" value="Test Field" />
   <br></br>

   <h:inputText required="true" />

   <h:commandButton action="#{contactBacking.submitComment}" value="Submit"
      <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form" />
   </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

EDIT: Edited as per @BalusC's answer.. and took screenshot of result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [`FacesContext#isValidationFailed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isValidationFailed%28%29) returns a `boolean` which is **never** `null`. Just get rid of that nonsensicial nullcheck.

```
<h:outputText value="Validation failed: #{facesContext.validationFailed}" />
```

Comment: True as your comment might be.. the result is still the same.. I actually know this works for a fact, I have used this in other projects, I actually also know that validation errors are being raised  since I´m using them in a custom component.. I can´t really figure out why this might be happening...